# encoding based on condition, somehow like an else if

Tags: vega-lite

this is my vega-lite spec

```
{
  
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"group": "I", "groupSort": 1, "segment": "A", "val": 1},
      {"group": "II", "groupSort": 2, "segment": "B", "val": -3},
      {"group": "III", "groupSort": 3, "segment": "A", "val": 2},
      {"group": "IV", "groupSort": 4, "segment": "B", "val": 3},
      {"group": "V", "groupSort": 5, "segment": "E", "val": -2}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {
    "type": "text", "size": 20,
    "text": "➟" 
    },
  "encoding":{
    "y": {
      "field": "group", "type": "nominal"
    },
    "color": {
                  "condition": {"test": "datum['val'] < 0", "value": "red"},
              "value": "green"},
     "angle": {
                  "condition": {"test": "datum['val'] < 0", "value": 90},
              "value": -45}     
  }
}
```

What I want is

- a red arrow if val is < 0
- a yellow arrow if val <= 0 && <3
- a green arrow if val >= 3

But I have no idea about the syntax :-(
Is this kind of logic possible in the encoding at all or do I have to move this to the transform?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your tests to an array as follows.

[image]

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"group": "I", "groupSort": 1, "segment": "A", "val": 1},
      {"group": "II", "groupSort": 2, "segment": "B", "val": -3},
      {"group": "III", "groupSort": 3, "segment": "A", "val": 2},
      {"group": "IV", "groupSort": 4, "segment": "B", "val": 3},
      {"group": "V", "groupSort": 5, "segment": "E", "val": -2}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "text", "size": 20, "text": "➟"},
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "group", "type": "nominal"},
    "color": {
      "condition": [
        {"test": "datum['val'] < 0", "value": "red"},
        {"test": "datum['val'] >= 0 && datum['val'] < 3  ", "value": "yellow"},
        {"test": "datum['val'] >= 3  ", "value": "green"}
      ]
    },
    "angle": {
      "condition": {"test": "datum['val'] < 0", "value": 90},
      "value": -45
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please provide some insights on how to read the documentation more successfully, as I did not found a hint that an array of tests would have been an option. Or any other "syntax"-similarity I should be aware of?

Comment: I didn't check the docs - I just guessed at  the syntax for this and it worked. A better way to learn is to look at all the examples and make sure you understand how everything has been created. Not everything is documented and there are some useful techniques in there which you can reuse. I also maintain a few advanced examples here which you can learn from: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase